# Entity - Multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Não estou entendendo o motivo deste erro no Entity. Poderia me dar um help?

> **Erro:** The role 'OcorrenciaHistorico_Ocorrencia_Target' of the relationship 'MoradaWeb.Models.OcorrenciaHistorico_Ocorrencia' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Model:

```
public partial class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public int? PessoaId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OcorrenciaHistorico> Historico { get; set; }

    public Ocorrencia()
    {
        Historico = new HashSet<OcorrenciaHistorico>();
    }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}

public class Historico
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public Pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
    public int pessoaId { get; set; }

    public int OcorrenciaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Ocorrencia Ocorrencia { get; set; }
}
```

O erro acontece ao salvar após ter adicionado um objeto no histórico.

```
Ocorrencia.Historico.Add(new OcorrenciaHistorico() { Acao = "Criação", DataCadastro = DateTime.Now, Ocorrencia = Ocorrencia, pessoa = pessoa });
```

Comment: Qual o resto do erro?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editei a pergunta acrescentando esta informação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O contexto está entendendo que `pessoa` é uma nova Pessoa, e não uma pessoa existente.

É melhor fazer assim:

```
var pessoa = db.Pessoas.Include(p => p.Ocorrencias).Where(...);
var ocorrencia = pessoa.Ocorrencias.Where(...);
ocorrencia.Historico.Add(new OcorrenciaHistorico() { Acao = "Criação", DataCadastro = DateTime.Now });
db.Entry(ocorrencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Ou selecionando pela Ocorrência também.

```
var ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Pessoa).Where(...);
ocorrencia.Historico.Add(new OcorrenciaHistorico() { Acao = "Criação", DataCadastro = DateTime.Now });
db.Entry(ocorrencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```